# .dll file issue in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, networking, dll

I have created my own Networking solution in Visual Studio for multiplayer in Unity. When connecting to the server I get the following errors:

> Unable to load attribute info on class MY_Server.Properties.Resources. Are you missing a reference?

> Unloading broken assembly Assets/Plugins/ByteBuffer.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime

Both my solutions and all of the included projects target .Net 6 but when i build my library the .dll file is targeting .Net 4x.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

I tried cleaning and rebuilding everything. Also I tried following tutorials to make a new networking solution. Nothing works.

Comment: You should not mix .NET framework 2.0-4.8 with new dotnet (the only common part is .NET Standard)

Comment: Having just tried I would suggest you have picked the wrong framework

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you for your help, I have suspected that this might be the reason so I deleted the project in the solution and recreated it making sure to target .Net 6 but it still got build targeting .Net 4x. So I recreated the whole solution targeting .Net 3.5 and now the .dll gets build targeting the 3.5 just as the rest. In your opinion is it wrong to use an older version instead of the .Net 6? I apologize in advance if my questions sound dumb and nonsensical. I ve never done anything like this before and development wise I m completely self tought.

Comment: why target .net 6? unity doesnt use .net 6.. i made one  targetting 4.7.2 and it went through fine

Comment: @BugFinder I thought that .net6 would offer long term support but as you noted unity doesn't use net 6 so I dropped it.  I made another lib for my needs targeting the same version as you (4.7.2) in my net 3.5 solution and you are right! It works just fine. Thank you so much for your help.